# Websphere App Server administration

Tags: websphere-6.1

How can I see all my webserver process running in Websphere application server administration?

Comment: Are they running on separate systems with no Node Agents installed?

Answer (score 0):

by saying webserver, I will assume you're talking about the IBM IHS server, not the java application server.

Whether your webserver process runs on a managed node (with node agent) or unmanaged node (without node agent), you should be able to see its status (running/not running) if you have setup the webserver properties (port number it runs on, IHS binary directories, etc...)